# Python calculate average

Tags: python

I am trying to find the average hr from the table below based on these conditions:
If age is between 20 and 30 years old and `mime > 0.40` and `hr > 100`

The code I have gotten so far...

```
import csv as csv 
import numpy as np

csv_file_object = csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'rb')) 
header = csv_file_object.next()
data=[]
for row in csv_file_object:
    data.append(row)
data = np.array(data)

hr = data[0::,0].astype(np.float)
mime = data[0::,1].astype(np.float)
age = float(input("Enter your age (in years): "))

if age > 19 and age < 31:
    i = 0
    for row in hr:
        if mime.all() > 0.4 and hr.all() > 100:
            hr = hr + i
    avghr = hr / len(hr)
    print avghr
else:
    print ('Age not in range')
```

The result I get:

```
Enter your age (in years): 25
[ 7.14285714  7.21428571  7.28571429  7.35714286  7.42857143  7.5
  6.42857143  5.17357143  5.21428571  7.85714286  8.57142857  9.28571429
  5.15642857  5.19142857]
```

My test.csv file:

```
hr, mime
100, 0.41
101, 0.19
102, 0.18
103, 0.6
104, 0.45
105, 0.7
90, 0.4
72.43, 0.17
73, 0.17
110, 0.5
120, 1
130, 2
72.19, 0.5
72.68, 0.5
```

My avghr should be 110, but I am no where near this.  If anyone can help that would be appreciated.

Comment: mime.all() is True, or 1, always > 0.4. hr.all() is True, or 1, always < 100, and besides, you never alter i from its initial value of 0, so hr=hr+i makes no sense. And you never would get to it because the condition is always False. Otherwise, you would be changing hr from a list to an integer inside the loop. And dividing hr (a list) by len(hr) (an integer) does not make sense to get an average. Please give another thought to the logic of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Why you used

```
 hr = hr + i
```

hr seems to be a list and that makes avghr = hr / len(hr) a list also.

You may try something like:

```
avghr = 0
for raw in hr:
    avehr += raw
avghr /= len(hr)
```

Hope it helps.